# Ruby htmlentities gem just stopped working, like magic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, html-entities

This has happened before. It goes DIRECTLY AGAINST the gem's usage documentation.

Even though I do this:

```
require 'htmlentities'
```

and then THIS:

```
coder = HTMLEntities.new
```

yields the following message:

```
undefined method `new' for HTMLEntities:Module
```

NO! NO NO NO NO NO! HTMLEntities is a CLASS. It is NOT a module.

What in the hell is going on here? All of my reports code is broken now!

I am using rvm. I scoured my project gem directory and the global gem directory. There is NO other occurrence of HTMLEntities other than in this gem.

IRB BEHAVIOR:

In irb, if I do:

```
require 'ruby gems'
```

and:

```
require 'htmlentities'
```

then the call to HTMLEntities.new works just fine.

Somebody please help.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? Are you using Bundler? Are you seeing this error in dev, production, or both? If you are using Bundler/Gemfile/Rails 3, have you tried *not* `require`-ing the gem?

Comment: This app is Rails v2.3.8, and this is in development. Doesn't matter whether I require it or not. Also I have included an update to show the irb behavior.

Comment: Sorry, that OSX Lion "helping" me.

Comment: so you require something before requiring HTMLEntities?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that it's getting required when it's already defined and the gem is doing something screwy in that case. You may test this theory with something like `require 'htmlentities' unless defined?(HTMLEntities)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh great, it looks like one of my programmers is also "helping" me. By putting adding a non-standard module in "vendor/plugins". And it appears that it has the name "HTMLEntities".

Comment: I'm glad it wasn't really magic! :)